# android options-menu not showing icons

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu

I have an activity in which i expand collapse views. I have added list view as a child and I am setting the visibilty of the list view on click of header.

Wgen i hide the list view my options menu does not show one icon. It shows the only icon added in tabhost.

Comment: Can you add your menu.xml. I guess you need to add `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"` tag in your xml, if you are running out of space

Comment: I am not using any xml or inflating.

Answer (score 1):

Add it to your menu.xml:

```
android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

or if you are adding elements programmatically:

```
@Override 
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater){
    menu.add("some menu").setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
}
```